# What is the function of Spring Session?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-session

A simple question, what is the use of Spring session where I can do a login with session using spring security? 
What feature can spring session offer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To put it simple, Spring Session project provides infrastructure for managing user's session.

Most notably, this includes replacing the `HttpSession` implementation provided by your Servlet container (e.g. Tomcat) with an implementation provided by Spring Session which is then persisted using `SessionRepository` implementation of your choice (Redis, Gemfire, Hazelcast, JDBC, Mongo are supported backends in current `1.2.0.RELEASE`). This ensures your sessions are stored in container/platform agnostic way and makes session clustering very easy.

Additionally, Spring Session provides some other nice features such as:

- configurable strategies for correlating user's requests with a session (either cookie or HTTP request header based)
- support for multiple sessions in a single browser instance
- WebSocket integration, meaning the `HttpSession` is kept alive when consuming only WebSocket
- ability to retrieve all the sessions for a given user

For more information please take a look at [Spring Session's user manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/) as it contains detailed guides which describe the most common use cases.