# What is the efficient way to manage single session across multiple microservices in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-session

I am working on a project, there I have two microservice, one for Authentication and Authorization, and other for doing some manipulations. I wanted to share the same session across both microservices. Currently, I am storing session in Redis and then managing it in both microservice.

Is this is an efficient way to do this? Please suggest if any?

Comment: It's an anti-pattern to use same session across microservices.  Ideally it should be token based.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37802329/what-is-the-function-of-spring-session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sid pointed out,  microservices are supposed to work stateless. Each request should be treated independently. If you need to access user information in your microservices, you can pass a signed token in the request with all claims. 
If you really want it to be stateful, Redis is best option.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite directly not possible to use the session across two applications. In this case, you are using two microservices.
I don't know your exact problem. I guess you are trying to have a transaction across two applications rather than sessions